# creating cursor for counting

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have this procedure :

```
    create or replace procedure check_max_game_rule_test (i_player_id IN NUMBER,i_max_games IN NUMBER, i_err_code OUT number)
is
  v_fixid number;
  v_count_fixid number;
  max_games_violation exception;

  cursor c1 is 
  SELECT ti.fixid,count(ti.fixid)
   FROM   BUS_SESSION BS,
                      CASINO_USERS CUP,                  
                      TICKET_ITEMS TI
               WHERE  BS.PARTY_ID =  4356
               AND    TI.BUS_SESSION_SESSION_ID = BS.SESSION_ID
               AND    NVL(BS.SESSION_CLOSE,'N') = 'N'
               and    CUP.parent_id = BS.AFF_ID
               AND    BS.SESSION_TYPE = 'TICKET SESSION'
    group by      TI.FIXID;    
    r1 c1%ROWTYPE;    
    begin
    open c1;
    loop 
    fetch c1 into v_fixid,v_count_fixid;
         if v_count_fixid > i_max_games
         then 
         raise max_games_violation;
 end if;
     end loop;
     close c1;
   end ;
```

the results which select returns is :
[image]

Procedure should count same fixid's and compare it to i_max_games and if count of that fixid is larger than i_max_games then raise exception..

Now i m getting encountered symbol c1

Can someone help me about this and is this cursor for getting and comparing fixid logical ?

Comment: there are 2 `begin`s , remove the first one .

Comment: Just saw it :)...

Comment: But is it loop good for this , after every input of fixid this procedures runs and checks is it count (fixid) > i_max_games.. ?

Comment: No. It is not clear what exactly you want. But, If your aim is to raise an exception for any `v_count_fixid > i_max_games`, you could filter it in a single sql by adding a `HAVING` clause and then raise an exception if count exceeds 0

Comment: Yes that is what I want ... Could you show me how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `CURSOR` loop for this. use a single select and raise exception based on the total count. Also, use ANSI `JOIN`s.

```
create or replace procedure check_max_game_rule_test (i_player_id in number, 
                                                      i_max_games in number, 
                                                      i_err_code  out number) 
is 
  v_count_fixid number; 
  max_games_violation exception; 
begin 
    select count(*) 
      into   v_count_fixid 
      from ( 
           select 1 FROM bus_session bs 
           join casino_users cup 
             on cup.parent_id = bs.aff_id 
           join ticket_items ti 
             on ti.bus_session_session_id = bs.session_id 
    where  bs.party_id = 4356 
           and nvl(bs.session_close, 'N') = 'N' 
           and bs.session_type = 'TICKET SESSION' 
    group  by ti.fixid 
    having count(ti.fixid) > i_max_games ); 

    if v_count_fixid > 0 then 
      raise max_games_violation; 
    end if; 
end; 
/
```

Comment: That would error if two ti.fixid rows were returned. You’d need to throw an outer count query around the select to ensure only a single row will be returned

Comment: What @Boneist said, or wrap your query into a `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END INTO v_something FROM dual`

Comment: Thanks @Boneist and Lukas

Comment: Sorry i didnt have time to look up , i tested it but this select returns me:
count(*)=0

Comment: @civesuas_sine : Check now. The `TICKET SESSION` was converted to lowercase by mistake

Comment: Now i get 1 in return, and in your select i get all 1 in return.

Comment: @civesuas_sine : You really need to understand the query and tell me what is wrong. If you tell "it returns 1", I can't understand what's the problem. Now that I have given you the idea as to how this can be done.You need to explore a bit and try to fix if there is any data issue.

Comment: Ok thank you very much i will explore , thank you i will mark your answer as correct ...